# Eclipse: Added jfxrt.jar to build path but errors still show up

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I want to run JavaFX on Windows Vista 32-bit. As my Eclipse Luna with java 1.8 is installed I added JavaFX to the project build path under

Project, Properties, Java Build Path, Add External JARs..., C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar

However, the following line is still underlined in red as an error by eclipse:

```
import com.sun.javafx.application.Application;
```

What should I do to fix it?

Note, I cannot run a newer development environment because Windows Vista 32-bit is old.

Comment: That's not the correct class to import. [`javafx.application.Application`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.html) needs to be imported instead.

Comment: Also, modifications to the JRE aren't picked up automatically--they don't exactly happen on their own. You'll have to redo the setup of that JRE on the Installed JREs preference page.

Comment: Just for future reference, you want to include the error in your question.

Comment: Thank you. How did you know to change the import. I am getting a runtime error due to a driver for my processor, but was able to compile.

Comment: I am now getting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54221226/10895179).