# Eclipse Luna and JavaFX. How do I update my processor's driver on Windows Vista 32-bit?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, intel, eclipse-luna

I am running Windows Vista on a32-bit processor. I am trying to launch a JavaFX program I compiled on Eclipse Luna with Java 1.8. The result is the following runtime error.

> Device "Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family" (\.\DISPLAY1) initialization failed :
>
> WARNING: bad driver version detected, device disabled. Please update your driver to at least version 8.15.10.2302

How do I get rid of the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Chipset for your processor isn't updated, you can find drivers [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/search?keyword=Intel%C2%AE+G45+Express+Chipset), hopefully this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've had a look at the processor drivers on the page, but they only go back to Windows 7. There are no drivers for Windows Vista there. What can I do?